# Validation in Struts 2 for 2 methods in the same action

Tags: validation, struts2

I'm developing with Struts 2 and I would like to validate 2 methods in the same action (which represents a user). The first is the login method which checks the role of the `user` `(admin or normal user)` and the second is to edit the `user` :

```
public class UserAccountAction extends AppSupport {

    public String login() {
        if (getUsername().equals("admin") && getPassword().equals("admin")) {
            session.put("username", getUsername());
            return "adminSuccess";
        } else if (getUsername().equals("user") && getPassword().equals("user")) {
            session.put("username", getUsername());
            return "userSuccess";
        } else {
            addActionError(getText("login.failedLoginCredential"));
            return INPUT;
        }
    }

    public String editProfile {
        // ...
    }
}
```

For that, I created 2 xml files : `UserAccountAction-login-validation.xml` :

```
<validators>
    <field name="login">
        <field-validator type="required">
            <message key="form.required" />
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="password">
        <field-validator type="required">
            <message key="form.required" />
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

The `UserAccountAction-editProfile-validation.xml` is the same with `lastname` and `firstname`.

The `struts.xml` :

```
    <action name="login" method="login" class="com.project.action.UserAccountAction">
    <result name="input">/jsp/login.jsp</result>
    <result name="userSuccess" type="redirect">home.html</result>
    <result name="adminSuccess" type="redirect">admin/home.html</result>
</action>

<action name="edit_account" method="editProfile" class="com.facilityrh.action.UserAccountAction">
    <result name="input" type="tiles">userEditProfile</result>
    <result name="success" type="redirect">account.html</result>
</action>
```

And the `login.jsp` :

```
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
    <div class="error"><s:actionerror /></div>
</s:if>

<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
    <div class="message"><s:actionmessage /></div>
</s:if>

<s:form action="login" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="login" key="login.login" /><br />
    <s:password name="password" key="login.password" /><br />
    <s:submit name="submit" key="login.submit" /> 
</s:form>
```

For the moment, in the action, the verification is basic but after, I'll use the database to get informations.

The problem is when I submit the form `(login or editProfile)`, the method is not executed because I've no error, I return on the same jsp (without the required messages next to input)

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the default interceptor stack? Do you *know* the `login` method isn't being executed or are you just *assuming* it isn't? Have you put in logging? Are you in devMode? Does you XML validation work? Why are you redirecting to non-S2 resources? In an MVC app everything (essentially) should go to a framework resource.

Comment: I'll use 2 interceptors to check if the user is an admin or an user but for the moment they return arg0.invoke(). I tried to only the line addActionError(getText("login.failedLoginCredential")); in the login method but no message in the jsp. I'm in devMode and with the validation xml files, I've messages next to input like what they're  required. Do you have an other method to have 2 types of redirect ?

Comment: So. Are you using the default interceptor stack? Do you *know* the `login` method isn't being executed or are you just *assuming* it isn't? Have you put in any logging? Does your XML validation work? Why are you redirecting to non-S2 resources? In an MVC app everything (essentially) should go to a framework resource. In other words, you answered almost *none* of my questions, which I wasn't asking for fun--the answers to those questions will provide the information necessary to resolve your problem.